# Optirun / Primusrun and Steam errors

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee, steam

When I run Steam using `optirun steam` it starts ok and Steam uses my nvidia card. But when I start a game, the following errors are printed on console:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/damluar/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/damluar/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 282070
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198045480716 [API loaded no]
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  15 (X_QueryTree)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x600003
  Serial number of failed request:  51
  Current serial number in output stream:  51
Segmentation fault
```

When I try to use `primusrun` instead, it seems not to use my nvidia card at all. Steam shows that it uses my Intel card, which doesn't support direct rendering and at game start I get:

```
Extension EXT_texture_compression_s3tc not supported. Shutting down the game.
```

I'm on Linux Mint 17.3 and my graphic card is GTX 760M.
I've also updated my nvidia driver is 352.63 recently, so may be it's relevant.